# Fixing ValueError train_test_split

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm trying to run a test code for an ML system and I keep getting ValueError for this line. I've tried downgrading the scikit-learn version to 0.19.1 after reading a similar question and it doesnt work either. Is there another solution?

```
(trainX, testX, trainY, testY) = train_test_split(data,
    labels, test_size=0.25, random_state=42)
```

The error code being

```
ValueError: With n_samples=0, test_size=0.25 and train_size=None, the resulting train set will be empty. Adjust any of the aforementioned parameters.
```

Comment: well, the error tells you that the number of samples is zero. can you print the result of `data.shape` and `labels.shape`?

Comment: just run this code: `print(data.shape)` and `print(labels.shape)` It gives you a tuple of size 2 for data, and a tuple of size 1 for labels. please report it

Comment: Look... sklearn says that you have 0 number of samples, which means your X matrix (which is data) is apparently empty... check this issue. just print the shape of your arrays as I said, or simply print them to make sure you have data in it

Comment: the results for data are (0, ) and the results for labels are (0, )

Comment: Well then it seems your arrays are completely empty. check your upstream codes to see why values are not assigned to your variables.